# OSGI configuration bundle

Tags: configuration, osgi

I'm new on diving in the OSGi world.
I'm trying to develop an application with the following modules(bundles):

- model
- services-api
- default-services
- web

Suppose the default-service bundle contains internal data access services.Therefore, it needs
some configuration for the database access.
It doesn't feel right to me to place the DB configuration within the default-services bundle.
Also, the web bundle should not know how the default-service is internally wired.

My question is: Does OSGi have a concept of configuration bundle? My idea was to deploy a bundle responsible for the default-service configuration. Is there a similar solution for that?

Comment: I hope you've read http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_kill_an_osgi

Comment: could you please specify which OSGI container do you use?

Comment: I'm using Karaf. But I would like my code to be OSGi agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at ConfigurationAdmin service? Your bundles should use ConfigurationAdmin to receive their configuration. If you use Declarative Services in your bundles, DS will automate the use of ConfigurationAdmin for you.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the standard way in OSGi, but if I understood correctly, ConfigAdmin stores the configuration file in different locations depending the OSGI container you use. Karaf, for instance use /etc to detect those files.

Comment: Unfortunately I was thinking in a solution where you install a bundle with the configuration.

Comment: Config admin is great for doing runtime configuration, but may be overkill for static configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you expect to do configuration, fragments may suit your needs.  They allow you to add extra information to the existing bundles classpath.  We use this to provide different configurations for different runtime environments (dev, test, ...).  You simply deploy the appropriate fragment bundle to have the correct configuration.

Comment: Thanks Robin, I will investigate this

Comment: It's a good idea, but I would like to not depend on the OSGi API

Answer (score 1):

I actually developed a little bundle that can detect configuration data in other bundles with the extender pattern. In my case this is a Jason file. Got some special tricks to handle passwords and binary files like ssl certificates.